# SQL pulling into Excel as text

Tags: sql, excel, vba

The data I'm pulling in from a SQL server is being *displayed* correctly as a date or number, but the data seems to be *stored* as text. For example, if I pulled in data with the number value 1, the cell would display "1" (no quotes) in it but Excel would not recognize it as a number - I can't perform any math to it and it won't be recognized as a number. I can fix that by selecting the cell and doing F2+Enter.

To clarify, the SQL data is not formatted in Excel as text. Changing formats does not solve my issue. The actual data in the cells isn't being recognized by Excel as numbers or dates, no matter what format I make the cells. I have to manually select and F2+Enter.

```
select distinct vl.Property As 'Property'
, vl.Property As 'Property number'
, vl.LeaseID as 'Lease ID'
, vl.priorleaseid as 'Prior lease ID'

from realpage_uds.dbo.property p

inner join realpage_uds.dbo.vwsa_lease vl
on p.propertyid = vl.propertyid


where p.name like '%Name%'
```

vl.LeaseID is a good example. It is data type "T-IDNumeric", system type "numeric" yet I can't select a leaseID and perform any arithmetic to it in Excel.

I'm pulling in the SQL data to Excel in the following way:

1. Go to "Data" tab, click "From Other Sources" under "Get External
   Data"
2. Choose "From SQL server", enter server name to connect
3. Connect to a database and choose a random table in the database
4. Click finish, and choose to pull in the data as a table or pivot table. I've used both and they both have this issue.
5. Finally, update the SQL query under connection properties, and change the query to my desired query that I have typed up. Then I choose "SQL" and hit OK.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way I can make the SQL data pull in as a number and date, and not have to manually select the cell and F2+Enter to get Excel to recognize the data?

Alternatively, if there is no way to change the way the SQL data pulls in, is there a macro I could implement to change all text data in a spreadsheet to number or date values?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you *pulling in* the data? It's  pretty relevant when trying to figure out what you can and can't do.

Comment: Please [edit] to put that information in your question. How the data is stored in the underlying table (column types) and specifics about the SQL statement you're using are relevant to the question, as I said. We're not really interested in a mention of what *everyone you've talked to* said; apparently you're interested in what others say, or you wouldn't be asking here. :-)

Comment: Fair enough! Does it look better or is there anything you think I should add?

Comment: Well, you added half of what I asked. :-) That's a start. Now how are you *pulling in the data*? You've shown how you're *selecting* the data, but that doesn't explain how it's getting from there to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `FORMAT(<<your field>>,'#') AS <<your alias>>` solve your problem? Try using 'd' for date. I don't have much experience pulling data from SQL Server, but in Access that's how I'd try to work around this issue.

Comment: Sorry to read that. the other options that spring to mind are: check if cells in spreadsheet aren't formatted as text, use `VALUE` and `DATEVALUE` in formulas to enable calculation on text records and third one would be to write a small macro to go through all cells and convert them to proper formats.
That' all in order how I would have checked it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Dates. Excel only recognized them as strings. To solve the issue I created a view that converted the Date to an Int and then set up excel to recognize the Int column as dates.

To convert dates to Excel date integers you can use this function:

```
DATEDIFF(day,'1899-12-30',@yourDate)
```

I do not have experience with numeric types, but you may try and cast it to a `decimal(18,4)` which works for me in Excel.

The above works for me using Azure SQL.